# Winter 22 Broke Event Listening Functionality

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, canvas

I have an aura component that includes a force:canvasApp with a signed post request authentication. The app uses /canvas/sdk/js/51.0/canvas-all.js to send a message to the aura component

```
window.Sfdc.canvas.client.publish
```

in the aura component I'm using

```
window.addEventListener("message", $A.getCallback(function event){//do things});
```

to listen for the specific event and then do something in salesforce, before winter 22 this was working great. Any idea's what might have changed or is this something salesforce is no longer allowing? Any alternative methods of sending a message from a canvas app to an aura component?

I'm actually not sure what's going on, the behavior is unreliable, it's doing weird things like if I navigate to a different page and come back then it works temporarily but then if I refresh the page and do the same navigation it stops working. Code runs fine on the canvas app side but messages sometimes get picked up on the salesforce side and sometimes don't. I'm going to dig a bit more with simplified example to see if I can isolate the issue

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

This was not an issue with Winter 22, it was an issue with a passport package I was using for authentication. I can confirm this method still works in Winter 22.